# Flutter http post response is limiting to 1023 characters

Tags: dart, flutter, http-post

I'm creating an app using Flutter, in this I'm creating a post request then reading the response as string (later to convert into json).

```
Future<String> post([String url = "https://example.com/get-new"]) async {

  return await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),

    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}).then((http.Response response) {

    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
      throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
    }
    return response.body;

 });
}

post().then((val){
  print(val);
});
```

It's working fine and getting the response, but as my question says, response is limited to 1023 characters. I checked it with Postman and found the response is coming properly as needed.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: you mean that you always have `response.body.length < 1024`? did you really try to `print('len: ${val.length})`?

Comment: @pskink , You are right, printing length gives: `len: 21220`

Comment: @Eugene, sorry Sir, but I need privacy until and unless I'm badly stuck

Comment: so you have the answer - i think you should check [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html)

Comment: @pskink, Thanks a lot Sir, I'll implement that tomorrow and will come here again with a solution or another question. I'm from India and now my shift time is completed and I'm leaving for the day ;-), Thanks again

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Dart `print()` has a limit of around 1024 characters. A workaround for this is by utilizing the `wrapWidth` parameter of `debugPrint()`. With this parameter set, the succeeding characters will be printed on a new line once the value is hit.

```dart
post().then((val){
  debugPrint(val, wrapWidth: 1000);
});
```