# API call in Flutter (dart)

Tags: api, http, flutter, dart

I have built one asp.net web api for my angular application which is working fine. I'm going to use same api in Flutter but surprisingly I'm not getting full object in **response.body**. I observed that, response.body is containing only 1023 chars.

```
final response = await http.post(
        apiUrl,
        body: body,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;',
          'Accept': 'application/json ',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $_token',
        });
print(response.body) // response.body string length is 1023.
```

Thank in advance looking at my issue.

Comment: Did you count the string printed or did you print the string length. FYI ```print``` method has a length limit. If you have long text, you should use ```debugPrint```. Also, there might be a response error in the body

Comment: Check this out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361422/flutter-http-post-response-is-limiting-to-1023-characters

Comment: print(response.body.length.toString()) gives me 6375 . It seems like data is there but print has some limitation. @danypata, I tried with debugPrint, but response.body is still limited to 1023 chars.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar issue it seems that print has a char limit to unlock use this change number to match ur response chars or just set a higher number and use printWrapped (response.body); instead

```
void printWrapped(String text) { 
     final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
      pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
   }
```

Comment: Worked for me. (only thing that before every bit of content, `I/flutter (17388):` is printed.)